# $\dim R/xR = \dim R - 1$

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings

Is it true that given a local noetherian ring $(R, m)$ that modding out by a regular element drops the dimension by 1? I may be misunderstanding my professor, but he claimed that as long as you choose an element that avoids the minimal primes and $m^2$, this should work.

I do know that it will drop the dimension by at least one by Krull's principal ideal theorem, but I can't see why it is exactly one.

Comment: The condition $x\notin m^2$ is not necessary.

Comment: Do you have a reference? I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: Corollary 2.3.5 [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~haution/SS17/Local_algebra.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, the lemma beforehand cleared up my confusion.